# facebook sso state check: CSRF state token does not match one provided

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

What are the basic steps for setting up a pure server flow facebook SSO, the docs are as usual a little ambiguous?

I set up the flow with javascript popups only to later realise you are not allowed to customise the login buttons.. which when you stick them next google and twitter sso the signin box look terrible.

http://www.codecademy.com/ seem to direct to their own server which then forwards onto a URL like this:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?response_type=code
&client_id=212500508799908&
redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.codecademy.com%2Fauth%2Ffacebook%2Fcallback&state=8aac5bc63c5afe8fbabe572021e7750579fefd898d7b4316&
scope=email%2Cpublish_actions
```

How is this URL being generated? In the facebook docs there is a function "[getLoginUrl](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginUrl/)".. is this being called which generates the correct URL?

I tried directing the user directly from their browser to:

```
var href =  'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?' +
        'client_id='+app_id+'&'+
        'redirect_uri=http://www.mysite.net/authenticate_facebook.php&'+
        'scope=email&';+
        'state='+$('body').attr('unique');
```

But the at the facebook php then the following recieving code resulted in errors about the 'state' not matching... I am assuming that the `state` is not just a random value generate by my server and must be aquired from the facebook server?

```
require_once(WEBROOT_PRIVATE.'authenticate/facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php');
$config = array(
    'appId' => 'xxx',
    'secret' => 'xxx',
    'fileUpload' => false,
    'allowSignedRequest' => false
);
$facebook = new \Facebook($config);
$user_id = $facebook->getUser();

if($user_id)
{
    try
    {

        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
    }
    catch(FacebookApiException $e)
    {
        error_log($e->getType(), 0);
        error_log($e->getMessage(), 0);
    }
}
```

SO, is this correct flow:

1 - Direct the user to my server facebook_auth.php

2 - facebook_auth.php generate  the get url and forwards the user onto it

3 - The user, if required logs into facebook, allows my app

4 - my facebook_auth.php script then checks the tokens and talks server to server with facebook to verify the rest

5 - my website then logs the user in

Comment: One of the reasonfor this error is -  if the user is already logged in and you are calling the getLoginUrl() method again. So make sure  u are not doing that the code follow the logic not to do so.

Comment: i have added to my question.. is the flow correct logic?

Comment: hmm so u sure that getLoginUrl() is not called again once the user is verified by FB login.

Comment: Yes the missing piece of the puzzle for me was creating the state from the facebook function getLoginUrl(). I was creating my own state instead. It now works.

Comment: yes also make sure dont store a session value called state this also sometime becomes culprit :)

Comment: thanks for the tips! i don't understand how the documentation for both facebook and google can be so confusing.. i am moving onto twitter sso.. fingers crossed this is a little more straight forward

Comment: Yeah I would recommend to use official doc always however thins always does not help and I bet you will realize once you do so FB opengraph sharing project :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue last week, and tracked it down to the state field being overwritten by multiple calls to getLoginUrl(). Each time you call getLoginUrl(), a new state token is generated in the SDK and stored in the $_SESSION (it's just a random value), so if you call it twice and the user uses the first link to log in, the second call will have reset the SDK's internal state token, and you will get this error in your logs.

The SDK looks for the same state token in the URL coming back after Facebook authorizes the user and redirects them back to your site, and if it doesn't match it will log this error (here's a link to the source).